# If I store date in mongodb as datetime, how do I display the date in json?

Tags: php, mongodb, datetime

What would be the type of the variable returned if the type of variable in mongodb is datetime?

When I convert it into json, what will be displayed? Will it be a large number like unix time stamp or what?

Comment: Note that straight encoding the date object will actually result in `{"$date": "2010-03-20 etc"}` not just the date. You must, at the moment, do that yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to use mongos native JavaScript Date objects.

You can convert date objects to and from Unix timestamps using 'getTime()' method or 'Date(milliseconds)'

Remember the JavaScript Date object is measured in milliseconds due to the the Unix epoch.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says it's a UTC DateTime. So expect it to be a string such as:
`2010-10-28T23:07:11Z`